# Select latest row for each unique combination

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have the following table:

```
Id          SubId        Date
----        -----        ----
1           1 
1           1
1           2
1           3
2           1
2           2 
2           2
2           3
```

How can I select the latest timestamp for each unique id/subID pair?
The results should be:

```
Id          SubId        Date
----        -----        ----
1           1            latest 1-1
1           2            latest 1-2
1           3            latest 1-3 
2           1
2           2 
2           3
```

SQL Server has Over Partition syntax that could be used to do something like tha t but as far as I'm aware MySQL does not support that?

I want to avoid having to execute multiple queries and prefer not to have to rely on some exotic MySQL specific syntax if possible.

Comment: could you tell us what the expected value is?

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn ǝpısdn See updated question

Comment: Does a group by and max(date) not work here?

Answer (score 1):

What about using group by ?

```
Select 
Id, SubId, Max(Date)
from myTable
group by Id, SubId
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know if it works:

```
SELECT id, DISTINCT(subid) from table ORDER BY date DESC;
```